# How can ensure that one thread will be executed after its main thread is finished ?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'd like to run a thread from the main thread , **but** I want this thread to be executed after the main thread is finished.
How should I do it ? 
Can I pass the thread a reference to the main thread and call to join() method ?

Comment: If you don't want them to run concurrently, why do you need 2 threads?

Comment: I want it to run concurrently , but just ensure that the main is finished before...

Comment: You want the main thread to finish before... _what_ exactly?  And ditto what Scott Hunter said:  You have a main thread that does something.  I don't know what it does, but let's call whatever it is `M()`.  Then there's something else you want to have happen after `M()` is done.  Let's call that `S()`.  Why can't your main thread simply do `M()` and then do `S()`?  What are you _really_ trying to accomplish?  (i.e., what is `S()`?)

Comment: @Sharon182: To paraphrase, "You use the word *concurrently*; I do not think it it means what you think it means."

Answer (score 1):

The closest would be a `shutdownHook`,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
  ...
});
```

But this would run will the process is still alive, once the process dies, thats it, you can't add any threads to a process that doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Runtime.getRuntime()` method for this. Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    .....
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            // run when the main thread finishes. 
        }
    }));
}
```

You can find more details about this in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))

Answer (score 0):

You can artificially do this with basic thread objects as follows, although I would recommend using the other answers on shutdown hooks instead.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // parametrizes with current thread
    new Deferrable(Thread.currentThread());
    System.out.println("main thread");
}

static class Deferrable extends Thread {
    Thread t;

    Deferrable(Thread t) {
        this.t = t;
        // optional
        // setDaemon(true);
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // awaits termination of given Thread before commencing
            t.join();
            System.out.println("other thread");
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            // TODO handle
        }
    };
}
```

This will always print:

```
main thread
other thread
```

Comment: Why do you say "artificially?"  And why do you think that `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(...)` is a better solution?  The original question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem):  The OP has not told us what she wants to accomplish.  She's all focused on what she _thinks_ is a solution to her problem, but we don't know what the actual problem is.

Comment: @jameslarge I do think that the answers mentioning the `addShutdownHook` are intrinsically better because the functionality is well scoped, while my answer does it, well, *artificially*, by joining a thread. This said, it might be considered as an alternative way to achieve the same.

Comment: @jameslarge this said, reading the comments back, it is a little unclear what the OP wants exactly - I agree.

Answer (score 0):

The typical synchronizer for this situation is a `CountDownLatch`. Have the spawned thread wait for the `CountDownLatch` prior to doing what it needs to, and have the main thread finish by calling `CountDownLatch.countDown()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1); // will need only one countDown to reach 0
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            latch.await(); // will wait until CountDownLatch reaches 0

            // do whatever is needed

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }).start();

    // do stuff

    // end main thread

    latch.countDown(); // will make the latch reach 0, and the spawned thread will stop waiting
}
```